# How to call static methods in functions? Scope of static methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, scope, static-methods

Suppose I create a class with a static method and want to run that method from another classes method or script function.

What is the scope of the static method?

ex:

```
def Class myClass:

     @staticmethod
     def mystaticmethod(input):
          print("blah")

def scriptfunc():
     myClass.mystaticmethod()
```

Is this valid?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `def Class myclass` isn't valid Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is valid.

But too elaborate on the purpose of `@staticmethod`, here's **Short** answer:

Declaring a `@staticmethod` would mean 2 things:

1. You don't care about the properties or attributes of a method as it's independent of other classes,
2. You do not require creating an `__init__` or a super method to override it's content or attributes, and doesn't require a subclass/parent class to handle itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `ClassName.methodName()`, from anywhere where `ClassName` is accessible (so, in the same enclosing scope, or in another module after having imported `ClassName`.

Python has [docs on namespace precedences, which you can read here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). Suffice it to say; for objects in general, their 'private' namespace is entirely accessible via the dot operator, as long as the object itself is accessible. This includes all variables and functions defined directly within.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers here seem to ignore that the first line is invalid Python code:

```
def Class myClass:
```

You probably meant to write this:

```
class myClass:
```

One thing to note is that the `@staticmethod` decorator is not necessary in this case:

```
In [111]: class myClass:
     ...:      def mystaticmethod(x):
     ...:           print("blah")
     ...:

In [112]: myClass.mystaticmethod(3)
blah
```

Adding it makes no difference:

```
In [113]: class myClass:
     ...:      @staticmethod
     ...:      def mystaticmethod(x):
     ...:           print("blah")
     ...:

In [114]: myClass.mystaticmethod(3)
blah
```